# unix command "&" options query

Tags: linux, unix

I am new to unix OS.
I am trying to understand & option given to a unix command.
Could anyone tell how to use this option.

eg:

```
$ << command>> &
```

OR

```
$ & << command >>
```

which one is correct way to use.

Comment: try this link I found about & https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/110822/using-bash-operator-with-delineator Does that help?

Comment: Type `man bash` and start reading. It is explained under the "SHELL GRAMMAR -> Lists" section.

Answer (score 1):

The correct way is adding the **& at the end**. That means your making the application to run in the background.

---

## Example:

`gedit file.c` , this will just open the `gedit` editor and you need to close it  in order to run the source code, this run application foreground `(fg)`.  The running process will block the shell terminal.

if you do `gedit file.c &` , this will run in the background `(bg)`.